# Relay Switching On and Off Rapidly During High Current Draw

Tags: capacitor, solar-energy, fluid-pump

I am building a solar pool heater using a solar panel to power bilge pumps that push water through irrigation pipes. When there's enough sun to get the panels to its typical voltage (~21.6V 6.16A) but not enough to provide enough current for the pump, then the relay cuts on and off rapidly until I turn down the potentiometer to a trickle. I'm just learning about electronics and have a basic understanding of the components, of which I assume I'm missing something important here.

I've currently wired this as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flgeRe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

```
Solar Panel -> Relay with cutoff at 10V -> Buck Converter to 12V -> Potentiometer -> 12V 2.5Amp Bilge Pump
```

Do I need to add a battery or a capacitor somewhere to ensure the relay has enough power to stay on or remain off when there isn't enough power overall? Is there a way to reserve enough current to power the relay and buck converter?

Thank you!

Actual components in use are:

- Solar Panel - [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00LXG4AXS/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LXG4AXS)
- Relay - [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07929Y5SZ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s02?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07929Y5SZ)
- Buck Converter - [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07JZ2GQJF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JZ2GQJF)
- Bilge Pump - [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01CPKB7BI/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s04?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CPKB7BI)

Comment: Provided that buying from Amazon and the like is not the best to get complete datasheets, I understand the saving of time. Could you explain why you use the relay? What you want to protect? the panels provide 12V, maybe you use 2 in series (and thus your statement on 23V). The buck converter will feed the pump at the correct 12V voltage. What is the real current absorption of the pump (officially 2A)? I think that even at reduced sunlight panels will provide enough current (5.5A I assume at max insolation).

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please edit your question and add a drawn schematic. The schematic tool seen when you edit your question is a breeze to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: @andrea I followed a youtube video, and it's clear in retrospect they didn't know what they were doing :) The Amazon description says 100W 12V, but the panel itself says something 23V at 5-6amps (it's outside and I can add more exact numbers soon) on the back. The buck converter reports a draw of ~1.91 amps at 12V when the pump is running at 100% (potentiometer fully turned).

The person on the youtube video seemed to intend for the relay to shut power off when the sun drops, rather than providing a continuous trickle. I'm treating this project firstmost as a learning experience.

Comment: @TonyM thanks for the warm welcome! I've never done such a schematic before, so I made my best attempt at it. I couldn't find anything resembling a DC motor, and I didn't know how to represent the component values properly. Feedback from anyone also appreciated if you have the time!

Answer (score 0):

First point. A solar cell is like a pn diode basically a current source up to a given voltage, above which the current reduces. When solar irradiance reduces, the I-V curve lowers. Please, have a look at a past discussion: [How to estimate solar panel output as a function of solar radiation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175200/how-to-estimate-solar-panel-output-as-a-function-of-solar-radiation)
I show the relevant image below.
[image]

Second point. The minimum voltage relay is proposed to avoid excessive discharging of batteries, to avoid to reduce the expected life. For the PV panels we do not have these problems. When sunlight is off they will not provide any current. I am not aware of any wearing due to low irradiance. Commonly used panels on roofs and PV parks are not switched off, but converters downstream are not operated for a  matter of efficiency and economy.

Conclusion. You can remove the "relay" from your scheme and see how things are going. The pump will not suffer of working at lower voltage and overheat because the converter guarantees the feeding voltage.

Remark. The relay would have been a good idea if there is some kind of hysteresis.
It was conceived for batteries, thinking of a constant discharge towards lower values. In your case you might have an increase of irradiance at dusk for some time, and also cause by moving clouds.
By the way even the buck converter will have a min input voltage, and will go off below that.